# HttpURLConnectionクラスのsetDoOutput(true)が機能しない

Tags: java, http, url, exception

```
    String Json = "{hoge}";

    URL url = new URL("http://hoge/hoge");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // HTTPリクエストコード
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(Json.length()));
    conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    System.out.println(conn.getDoOutput());
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
```

上記のソースを実行しますが、

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

が機能しません。

```
System.out.println(conn.getDoOutput());
```

でfalseと表示され

```
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
```

でExceptionが発生します。

```
java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)
```

原因がわからず、困窮しております。
どなたかご助力いただけますでしょうか？

setDoOutput(true)
を記述していますが、DoOutputにtrueがセットされません。

Comment: System.out.println(conn.getDoOutput());の次の行にSystem.out.println("test!");を追加したとき、`false`の後に`test!`と表示されますか？

Comment: `false`
`test!`
と表示されました。

Comment: [`HttpURLConnection/URLConnection#setDooutput()`の実装](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/URLConnection.java#L907-L910)からしてそういう挙動になるとは考えにくいですが、実際に問題が発生しているコードはここに書いているそのままでしょうか？

Comment: 実際に問題が発生しているコードはここに書いているそのままになります。URLやJsonの値は実際のものとは異なりますが、コードの順番には相違ありません。